# How do I solve the equation $\Delta\phi=-\frac{k}{r^2}\phi$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

So, as title says, I'm trying to solve the equation below for $\phi(x, y, z)$

$\Delta\phi=-\frac{k}{r^2}\phi$

Where $\Delta=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$ and $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$

Considering that space is isotropic

$\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}=\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2}$

How do I solve it?

Comment: Maybe you should try https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplacesEquationSphericalCoordinates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This trick is famous when $\phi$ only depends on $r$:
$$\Delta\phi=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r})\phi=\frac{1}{r^2}(r^2\phi''+2r\phi').$$
I think your equation reduces to the equation,
$$r^2\frac{d^2\phi}{dr^2}+2r\frac{d\phi}{dr}+k\phi=0$$
and this is apart from other classifications, a Strum's Liouville Equation.
It's solution is luckily simple:
$$\phi(r)=c_1r^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{1-4k}}{2}}+c_2r^{-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{1-4k}}{2}}.$$
If I interpreted your isotropy condition correctly. Some documents said depends on $\ln r$, the same thing I think.